# How to properly use React.StatelessFunctionalComponent<Props> on a stateless functional component?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I need to add flow annotation for a react stateless functional component.
Accordingly to docs I should use `React.StatelessFunctionalComponent<Props>`

Which has the following signature [Ref.](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-statelessfunctionalcomponent):

> type StatelessFunctionalComponent =   (props: Props) =>
>   React.Node

But I receive several [errors](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gFSgCGAzqAEoCmRAxnpFrKqAORbV0uKLCGUnRkAOxwBaACbISRAEbRKoIbFEBXIeMqQCwRDgCe6BQAVG6EgBUDCgLygA3olCgA1OKI5KALkUrUMylgANI4uHhgAssLeQr7+QSHOYejhRAAe0bEBwU7OyDSwQgDCsBqeMX5ZCfDUOAAWAQAi-DRYyOg4yAWeJDitQgDmiAC+PHwCwmKUQrLyispqGlr4Ooj5Qj2gAGLYlDSkOA1EeqC2ABR2oG4egaBJkUI3d2k3eQXFGjfV7vVYTSQtbQ6BVAQ08JlgZkshgAlJ4qLQcAA6ADKOHclHkJBImzUdE602gxQwBSmOAAPODIVYAHwnWkOJzsHAqLBCUCnEJOMmSABu1M5TlA3OQfLsV0oQzJwF5tIFXJlcsFwr5isF9juwiGADIAMQARgA7AA2ADcqqF0pF-LVauV1ptarsT1S2v1xrNDq5lpVDqlCt9-s9di+dUazVa7XxI193vtXsD0OGiEoqUwuEumiIKmgeG27D2PUOekQQA).

What am I doing wrong here and why?

```js
// @flow
import * as React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
import IconWeather from '../../shared/icon/IconWeather'

/* eslint-disable no-undef */
type PropsType = {
  +date: number,
  +tempMin: number,
  +tempMax: number,
  +iconCode:number,
  +weatherDescription:string
}
/* eslint-enable no-undef */

const ForecastDay = ({ date, tempMin, tempMax, iconCode, weatherDescription }:PropsType):React.StatelessFunctionalComponent<PropsType> => {
  const dateFormat = moment.unix(date).format('ddd, MMM D')
  const tempMinRounded = Math.round(tempMin)
  const tempMaxRounded = Math.round(tempMax)
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{dateFormat}</div>
      <div>
        <IconWeather code={iconCode} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          {tempMinRounded}&#176;
        </div>
        <div>
          {tempMaxRounded}&#176;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {weatherDescription}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default ForecastDay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem by adding

```
 const ForecastDay:React.StatelessComponent<PropsType>
```

and use as returned type `ReactElement<any>` or `React.Element<*>`.

```js
// @flow
import * as React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
import IconWeather from '../../shared/icon/IconWeather'

/* eslint-disable no-undef */
type PropsType = {
  +date: number,
  +tempMin: number,
  +tempMax: number,
  +iconCode:number,
  +weatherDescription:string
}
/* eslint-enable no-undef */

const ForecastDay:React.StatelessComponent<PropsType> = ({ date, tempMin, tempMax, iconCode, weatherDescription }:PropsType):ReactElement<any> => {
  const dateFormat = moment.unix(date).format('ddd, MMM D')
  const tempMinRounded = Math.round(tempMin)
  const tempMaxRounded = Math.round(tempMax)
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{dateFormat}</div>
      <div>
        <IconWeather code={iconCode} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
          {tempMinRounded}&#176;
        </div>
        <div>
          {tempMaxRounded}&#176;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        {weatherDescription}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default ForecastDay
```